# Why is an overwritten css rule still affecting my markup?

Tags: html, css

I have a simple ordered list and I want to display the list-style-type as decimal.  The problem is I have a css reset file setting all lists to none.

I am setting my ordered list as follows.

```
ol#note{ 
   list-style-type:decimal !important;
}
```

I see in firebug that the css resets declaration has a line going through it..  which i assume means its being overwritten.  However I am not seeing any of those numbers.  Once I disable that declaration in the css reset file my numbers re-appear.  Can anyone explain whats going on?

Comment: this probably has something to do with the [css specificity rules](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/)

Comment: wouldnt ol#note be more specific than just ol ?

Comment: ok for some reason the rule needed to be applied to ol#note li instead

Comment: I would think so too, and I don't know much about these rules myself, it's just the only thing I can think of. I assume your stile sheets are in the right order (reset.css first, then your own stylesheet).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

maybe with this:

```
ol#note li{
   list-style-type:decimal !important;
}
```